# External JavaScript file not running

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've tried running the following E-mail list application on Chrome but can't seem to get the JavaScript to execute.  The HTML works fine.  Any suggestions or best practices for this application to work?  I've included the external JavaScript file too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=”UTF-8”>
<title>Join E-mail List</title>
<script src = "index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<h1> Please join our email list</h1>
<form id=”email_form” name=”email_form”
action=”join.html” method=”get”>
<label for=”email_address1”>E-mail Address:</label>
<input type=”text” id=”email_address1” name=”email_address1”>
<span id=”email_address1_error”>*</span><br>

<label for=”email_address2”>Re-enter E-mail Address:</label>
<input type=”text” id=”email_address2” name=”email_address2”>
<span id=”email_address2_error”>*</span><br>

<label for="first_name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
<span id="first_name_error">*</span><br>

<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="join_list" value="Join Our List">
</form>
</main>
</body>
</html>
enter code here
```

**External JavaScript file (index.js)**

```
/* This application validates a user's entry for joining our E-mail 
    list
*/

<script>
var $ = function(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);

//This function gets and validates the user entries

var joinList = function() {
var emailAddress1 = $("email_address1").value;
var emailAddress1 = $("email_address2").value;
var firstName = $("first_name").value;
var isValid = true;

//This validates the first entry

if ("email_address1 = "") {
$ ("email_address1_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This is 
required.";
isValid = false;

if (email_address2 = "") {
$ ("email_address2_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This is 
required.";
isValid = false;

if ("first_name = "") {
$ ("first_name_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "First name is 
required.";

}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have `”curly quotes”` in many places, and the syntax highlighting on this post clearly shows the error in your JS.

Comment: Also you don't need script tags in .js files, only when you include JavaScript in a html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of index.js should be fixed:

```
var $ = function(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);

//This function gets and validates the user entries

var joinList = function() {
var emailAddress1 = $("email_address1").value;
var emailAddress1 = $("email_address2").value;
var firstName = $("first_name").value;
var isValid = true;

//This validates the first entry

if ("email_address1" == "") {
$ ("email_address1_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This is required.";
isValid = false;

if ("email_address2" == "") {
$ ("email_address2_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This is required.";
isValid = false;

if ("first_name" == "") {
$ ("first_name_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "First name is required.";

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax errors @Maxim. Appreciate it.  I'm still having issues with Chrome executing the JavaScript though.  Let me try going for a run and coming back to it in a bit.  
thanks for the input.